# Magento Fedex integration

Tags: magento, fedex

I am trying to integrate fedex shipping in default magento system. i have created fedex sandbox account and added the credentials in fedex settings in admin. In frontend I am able to choose rate from fedex and complete the order.

But when I tried to ship that order from admin, I could not create shipping label as it says
Commodity country of manufacture is required; Shipper Postal-State Mismatch; Shipper Postal-City Mismatch;

I have tried many times with many address but could not create the shipping labels from fedex. Any ideas how to get started with fedex shipping label.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the guide about setting FedEx shipping method in Magento.

Step 1. Go to: FedEx Developer Resource Center and create developer’s account.

Step 2. When you create developer’s account go to Developer Resource Center and click on top navigation FedeEx Web Services -> FedeEx Web Services for Shipping.

Now, you will see the link Develop & Test Your Application (about testing, obtain developer test key) click on it. Then you only have to send the request for the test environment, you can see the link “Obtain Developer Test Key” click on it and fill the form. After sending the form with data, you will receive an email message from FedEx with all required data for testing FedEx shipping method.

In this email message, you will get Test Account Number:xxxxxxxxx (for FedEx Web Services for Shipping only) and you have to insert this number in field Account ID in FedEx config section, take a look at below image.

[image]

Step 3. When you’re almost ready to launch:
After you’ve successfully tested your application and are ready to go into production, go to the FedEx Developer Resource Center to obtain your Production key.

For More Details Please visit this below URL:

http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html